# Recursive function to get a decimal number out of a list of binaries

Tags: c++, recursion

If I have a list with N elements that represent a binary number, and each node (I named it info) is a boolean (true = 1, false = 0) what would the best way to get the decimal value using a recursive function be?

I tried using google but I only came with the formula for decimal;

```
1 * 2N  +  0 * 2N-1   + 0 * 2N-2  + ... + 1 * 21  +   1 * 20
```

Right now I have a header and some basic structure for the method, according to what I understand of the problem. Also the problem says the first digit is the most significative but I don´t quite get if that is relevant.

```
int Lista:: ConvierteBinarioDecimal ( void ) const;
static int suma= 0;


ConvierteBinarioDecimal();
}
return suma;
}
```

And the Nodo (node) class.

```
class Nodo{
public:
    bool Nodo::getInfo(void);   //Retorns the content of info   
    Nodo* Nodo::getNext(void);  //Retorns the cotent of next

private:
    bool info;
    Nodo *next;
};

class Lista{
    Nodo *primero;
    int longitud;
};
```

I started learning C++ last week and so far it has been way more tough than Java >_< so any help would be a godsend.

Comment: By `decimal` do you mean `int`?

Comment: Yeah, actually thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive example:

I have to do some little changes, adding **const** to **getInfo** (there is no problem here) and adding **const** to **getNext** (you could need also and non-const version), the problem was that function `ConvierteBinarioDecimal` is declared as `const` which is good (don't have to change anything for calculating decimal representation, but this force, that the two method need to be `const`) you could add non-const version if needed.

The `static int ConvierteBinarioDecimal(Nodo const* node) {` is the recursive implementation of the conversion to decimal from binary. If it need to be recursive this is your sample code, if you could use an iterative version would be better for performance.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Nodo {
public:
    bool getInfo(void) const { return info; }  // Retorns the content of info
    Nodo* getNext(void) const { return next; } // Retorns the cotent of next

    Nodo(bool i, Nodo* n) : info(i), next(n) {}

private:
    bool info;
    Nodo* next;
};

class Lista {
    Nodo* primero;
    int longitud;
public:
    int ConvierteBinarioDecimal(void) const;
    Lista(Nodo* p, int l) : primero(p), longitud(l) {}
};

static int ConvierteBinarioDecimal(Nodo const* node, int decimal = 0) {
    if (node == NULL) // prefer C++11 nullptr
        return decimal;
    decimal *= 2;
    if (node->getInfo())
        decimal++;
    return ConvierteBinarioDecimal(node->getNext(), decimal);
}

int Lista::ConvierteBinarioDecimal(void) const {
    return ::ConvierteBinarioDecimal(primero);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Lista list(new Nodo(true, new Nodo(false, new Nodo(true, new Nodo(true, NULL)))), 4);
    std::cout << list.ConvierteBinarioDecimal() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, specially for explaining it to me, I´ll have to study the code further to truly understand but your explanation is a nice start.

Comment: @NetVipeC His code (prototype) suggests that he needs to do this without using parameters to his recursive function.

Comment: You will need then to add a method to `Nodo` for calling in the `Lista` method. The code provided, has another `free function` called `ConvierteBinarioDecimal` that return `suma` (with i assume is where the conversion was supposed to storage. I think it's a really good tradeoff to eliminate the `static variable` and `the free method` for only adding one help method.

Comment: Some fix made to the code, previously the binary was calculated _less to more significant bit_, now is as you needed _more to less significant bit_ The test call in the sample is (true, false, true, true) or 1011 binary = 11 decimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConvierteBinarioDecimal()
{
    int indice = longitud;
    Nodo *corriente = primero; // current, begin at first node
    while (corriente != null)
    {
        if (corriente->getInfo())
            suma += 1 << --indice; // use bitshifting to add this binary digit
            // alternatively, this could be "suma |= 1 << --indice;"
        corriente = corriente->getNext(); // go to next node
    }
}
```

I hope the Spanish helps as well! :)

Comment: This actually work! Thanks a lot. But to make the function recursive do I only have to add a call to itself at the bottom?

Comment: By the way thanks for the spanish, my english is normally better but my keyboard is broken right now.

Comment: Ah, to make it recursive you will have to make a couple of changes. I'll edit my answer to show this.

Answer (score -1):

One of the fastest ways to do this is to use bit shift operations.  So, for example:

```
long decimal = 0;
Nodo * current = primero;
unsigned int bitcounter = 0;

while(current)
{
    if(current->getInfo)
    {
        long temp = 1;
        temp << bit counter;
        decimal |= temp;
    }
    bitcounter++;
    current = current->next;
}
```

Basically, what I've done here is to look at each bit in a while look.  Note how I traverse the linked list.  I stop when `current->next` is null by checking `current` in the following iteration.  I also keep track of which bit I'm processing.  For each bit, if the bit is `1`, I place that into a temporary variable and shift it over to the right position using the `<<` operator. Then I `OR` this temporary variable with the running total using the `|=` operator (OR and assignment).

Now, to do this recursively:

```
long ConvertBinaryToDecimal()
{ 
    static long decimal = 0;
    static Nodo * current = primero;

    // Base case
    if(!current)
    {
        current = primero;
        long result = decimal;
        decimal = 0;
        return result; 
    }
    else {
        decimal = decimal<<1;
        if(primero->getInfo())
            decimal |= 1;

        current = current->next;
        ConvertBinaryToDecimal();
}
```

Comment: This is close, but incorrect. The problem states that the first digit is the most significant, but you take it to be the *least* significant.